# What type of database does CiviCRM use?

Tags: database

I'm sure this is a very obvious question but what type of database does CiviCRM use?  SQL Server, MYSQL, etc.

Comment: You might be just using shorthand, but CiviCRM is more than a database, it's a CRM. The database is just where most of the data is stored, i.e. CiviCRM uses a database, but it's not a database per-se.

Comment: Good point Alan. I decided to Edit to make that clear

Answer (score 2):

From [CiviCRM Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades)

An installation of Drupal, Joomla or Wordpress, and the following additional requirements:

PHP 5.5+ is recommended. See the CiviCRM PHP Requirements page for details.
PHP memory_limit set to between 256 and 512 megabytes.

MySQL 5.1.x or higher with INNODB support : CiviCRM is compatible with the current generally available MySQL release. Trigger support is required for logging and multi-lingual features. SUPER privileges are required in MySQL 5.1 if binary logging is enabled.

Surprised if this (or other places which reference mysql) was hard for you to find, so please suggest where you think the documentation could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM utilizes PHP/MySQL. Info on installation and requirements can be found here: 
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades